# Object returning null from hashmap

Tags: java, object, null, hashmap

Hi I'm working on a Uni assignment and I currently have a class called `Program` that stores a `hashmap` called `courses`.

inside the `Program` class I can easily return objects from the `Hashmap` but when I try to retrieve a `Course` object from the `Hashmap`in another class `University` it always returns `null`.

a snippet of my code:

Program Class

```
private Map <String, Course> courses = new HashMap<String, Course>();

public void addCourse(Course newCourse) throws ProgramException {
        setCode(newCourse.getCode());
        courses.put(newCourse.getCode(), newCourse);    
    }

    public Course getCourse(String courseID){
        setCode(courseID);
        return courses.get(courseID);
    }
```

University Class

```
    public void enrollIntoCourse(String courseID) {
            studentKey = student.getFullName();

            course = program.getCourse(courseID);

// print out Course Object to check. But it = null!!
            System.out.println(course);

            enrolled.put(studentKey, course);

        }
```

Basically I am trying to get a `Course Object` from the `courses` `Hashmap` to store in another `Hashmap` that holds `Course Objects` but with a different key.

Comment: Are you sure that courseId and code are the same attributes of Course class?

Comment: Are you sure your `Map<String, Course> courses` contains what you think it does? Try printing it before your try and `get`.

Comment: Are sure that courses are added to `program` instance variable in `University` class before invoking enrollIntoCourse method?

Comment: There's no magic to a `HashMap`. If it returns `null` then there is no entry with the given key.

Comment: Yeah I have checked the courses hashmap and it contains the objects I need to get from it but for some reason the get method isn't retrieving the objects for the Univeristy class

Answer (score 0):

I would check that you have properly initialised `program` and have added courses to it. If you are confident that you've done that, could you show us the code that does so?